# FB.ui not working

Tags: api, facebook-javascript-sdk

After logging into our facebook application  - after allowing access if I call  -

```
FB.ui({ method: 'permissions.request', perms: 'email', access_token: accesstoken }, function(granted) {
          if (granted.perms) {
                         //Do things here
}
});
```

This shows up a dialog box that keeps on loading and loading.This used to work
one month before.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has migrated to OAuth 2.0:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Try:

```
FB.login( function( response ) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // user granted permissions
    }
}, { scope: "email" } );
```

Comment: Tried the same, but that opens up an iframe window that remains open even after granting permission.

Comment: You should post additional info. Do you get any errors in the console? How do you initialize the JS SDK? Does the issue occur in a particular browser or not? Etc..

Answer (score 0):

FB.ui still works.I do not have to use FB.login.I have added this line earlier FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode = function(a, b) { FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id] = b; }; to close the un necessary iframe window coming up in IE after login.That was the root cause .Commented the same .It works as it was earlier.Only thing I had to close the pop up was using jquery and css.

Comment: Still I recommend you to migrate to OAuth2.0 as you never know when this will stop working. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/.